# The Puzzling Phone

Tags: mathematics, probability, no-computers

The amazing "*Puzzling Phone*", comes in two models, one sold by "*Super Puzzling Inc*", and one sold by "*Mega Puzzling Ltd*"

Phones need to have government testing before they can be sold on the market.

Through this testing, it turns out that a third of the "*Super Puzzling Inc*" models on the market work for over 10 hours on a single charge, and measurements have been conducted that revealed half of the "*Mega Puzzling Inc*" models last for over 10 hours on a single charge. Battery testing, as you all know, is very important! (:D)

"*Super Puzzling Inc*" is a very large company with a lot of resources, hence why 70% of the market is filled with its Puzzling Phones. The consumers have spoken and they simply like the new "Jet Black" colours that are available, which the other company doesn't sell. The new "Rose Gold" colours are also just wonderful!

You have completely randomly purchased a brand-new "*Puzzling Phone*", however, it is unlabeled, so you don't know which company of the two manufactured it, and additionally, you have not taken a look at the box or its contents at all.

What's the chance it lasts for more than 10 hours on a single charge? Assume that it was sold already fully charged from the beginning.

(Note: You should ignore any technological equipment such as the screen, processor, etc, and  treat this as a mathematical question.)

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/52710/discussion-on-question-by-cipherriddle-the-puzzling-phone).

Comment: On the other hand, nobody will be able to get a proper solution. Please clarify: Are we to find a solution in terms of some variables, or derive an exact numerical answer?

Comment: That was the main confusion.

Comment: No. I'm not claiming that it is *difficult*. I'm saying that there is no answer. What actual information *do* you think we have?

Comment: I'm not retracting it. If you like, you could email me the solution - my email address is listed on my profile. I've also posted your comment in the chat; other people can vote to reopen if they would like to.

Comment: @CipherRiddle "when it had no proper attempts at an answer": in what way was my answer *not a proper attempt*? (It may have missed some super-clever thing you have in mind that makes there actually be a meaningful answer despite the apparent absence of any usable information; but how was it not a proper attempt?)

Comment: As I said in my other comment, you can email me the solution and I'll take a look at it. You don't have to, though.

Comment: I posted my answer before anyone claimed that there is no answer; how can it possibly have been a comment on that claim?

Comment: @GarethMcCaughan @ Deusovi Due to popular request, I've modified the puzzle, it now looks less strange and hopefully is easier to understand.

Comment: Well, it now looks entirely different, in that (with some reasonable assumptions) it has a definite solution. But it's now unambiguously a basically-routine mathematics problem and not a puzzle -- and I don't see how a solution to the question as it now stands could possibly be a solution to the question in its previous form.

Comment: @GarethMcCaughan It's not "entirely" different, just previously it had no numbers, but was still solvable. Since I got requests to clarify the post, I added some numbers, and the core idea is the same, you just have to use  those available numbers to get a solution. If this puzzle is still not up to PSE standards, then I'm not sure what more I could do after all of this, however, I would appreciate any feedback.

Comment: I've adjusted my answer so that it solves the basically-routine mathematics problem that the question has turned into. However, being a basically-routine mathematics problem this should surely be closed as such. Unless, of course, I'm missing something and it's not really a brmp. What I would actually like to know is what sort of answer CipherRiddle thought appropriate for the *original* version of the question.

Comment: This is now not a puzzle; it is simply an exercise in probability.

Answer (score 1):

[The question has been edited and greatly changed in the process; so, accordingly, has my answer.]

(I don't see that this is actually a *puzzle*, unless there is some steganographic thing going on to give the actual answer.)

It's not perfectly clear what it means to say that you have "completely randomly" purchased a phone. I shall take it to mean something equivalent to this: Of all the phones of these two kinds to be sold this year, you picked a random one and bought it. This means that there's a 70% chance that your phone comes from SPI, and a 30% chance that it comes from MPL. In the first case, the probability of long battery life is 1/3; in the second, it's 1/2. Accordingly, the probability that your phone's battery is long-lived is 0.7*1/3 + 0.3*1/2 = 7/30+3/20 = 14/60+9/60 = 23/60.

If instead you had someone flip a coin and pick a brand corresponding to the result, your probability of long battery life is 1/2*1/3 + 1/2*1/2 = 5/12.

The original version of the question omitted all the specific numbers but still appeared to ask for an actual numeric answer. If the OP would care to explain how that was meant to work, I would be interested.

Comment: I really appreciate this, but for questions like this I honestly think leaving them unanswered is better. (It's almost certainly going to be closed soon, anyway...)

Comment: I'm always in two minds about it.

Comment: (Note: the previous comments were written when the question took its earlier form -- though they may well apply equally to its current form.)